# I want to Reference a Cell in the same Workbook to change the Period Number in a Excel Sage Sequel Database Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

New to the site, have done a lot of VBA coding, but still a novice learning Excel Power Query, the majority pulling from our Sage Sequel Database in various forms and queries with success.
My expert colleague has now left the business, so am trying to teach myself.

I am trying to change the PeriodNumber in Bold below in the Power Query dynamically from Cell E2 in the same Workbook tab "Prior Month Nominal". I have converted Cell E1 (heading) and E2 (Formula giving Month Number) into a Table and also created a Connection Only Query in the Workbook.

[image: Excel Tab "Prior Month Nominal"]

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("XXXX\SAGEXXX", "UKXXXXXXLtd", [Query="SELECT #(lf)NLNominalAccount.AccountNumber, NLNominalAccount.AccountCostCentre, NLNominalAccount.AccountDepartment, NLNominalAccount.AccountName,#(lf)NLPostedNominalTran.TransactionDate, NLPostedNominalTran.PostedDate, NLPostedNominalTran.GoodsValueInBaseCurrency, NLPostedNominalTran.Reference,#(lf)NLPostedNominalTran.Narrative, NLPostedNominalTran.UniqueReferenceNumber, NLPostedNominalTran.UserName, NLPostedNominalTran.UserNumber,#(lf)SYSAccountingPeriod.PeriodNumber#(lf)FROM NLPostedNominalTran, NLNominalAccount, SYSAccountingPeriod, SYSFinancialYear#(lf)WHERE NLPostedNominalTran.NLNominalAccountID = NLNominalAccount.NLNominalAccountID#(lf)AND NLPostedNominalTran.SYSAccountingPeriodID = SYSAccountingPeriod.SYSAccountingPeriodID#(lf)AND SYSAccountingPeriod.SYSFinancialYearID = SYSFinancialYear.SYSFinancialYearID#(lf)AND SYSFinancialYear.YearRelativeToCurrentYear = 0#(lf)AND SYSAccountingPeriod.**PeriodNumber = 8**#(lf)ORDER BY NLPostedNominalTran.UniqueReferenceNumber DESC"]),
```

The Connection Only Query has the following Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="MonthNo"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Month No", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

The Table I am referencing to is named "MonthNo"

I am trying to dynamically change the PeriodNumber = X above referencing a cell in the workbook as I change the Month.

I have tried adding a Parameter before the Source line above as follows

`ANDPeriodNo = MonthNo` and changing where the PeriodNumber = to MonthNo.

I have also tried to add into where 'PeriodNumber =' the following, as suggested by some websites

`PeriodNumber = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="MonthNo"]}[Content],`

The Query keeps coming up with Syntax Error at Source? Whilst other Queries I have tried mimicking have a Parameter line before Source.

I would appreciate please if someone could help me with some patience?

Cheers

Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, where MonthNo is a single cell workbook range name containing 8

```
let
MonthNo= Text.From(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="MonthNo"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]),                                 
Source = Sql.Database("XXXX\SAGEXXX", "UKXXXXXXLtd", [Query="SELECT #(lf)NLNominalAccount.AccountNumber, NLNominalAccount.AccountCostCentre, NLNominalAccount.AccountDepartment, NLNominalAccount.AccountName,#(lf)NLPostedNominalTran.TransactionDate, NLPostedNominalTran.PostedDate, NLPostedNominalTran.GoodsValueInBaseCurrency, NLPostedNominalTran.Reference,#(lf)NLPostedNominalTran.Narrative, NLPostedNominalTran.UniqueReferenceNumber, NLPostedNominalTran.UserName, NLPostedNominalTran.UserNumber,#(lf)SYSAccountingPeriod.PeriodNumber#(lf)FROM NLPostedNominalTran, NLNominalAccount, SYSAccountingPeriod, SYSFinancialYear#(lf)WHERE NLPostedNominalTran.NLNominalAccountID = NLNominalAccount.NLNominalAccountID#(lf)AND NLPostedNominalTran.SYSAccountingPeriodID = SYSAccountingPeriod.SYSAccountingPeriodID#(lf)AND SYSAccountingPeriod.SYSFinancialYearID = SYSFinancialYear.SYSFinancialYearID#(lf)AND SYSFinancialYear.YearRelativeToCurrentYear = 0#(lf)AND SYSAccountingPeriod.PeriodNumber ="&MonthNo&"#(lf)ORDER BY NLPostedNominalTran.UniqueReferenceNumber DESC"])
in Source
```

Comment: Thanks horseyride, will give it a try in the morning when in the office.

Comment: Hi horseyride, I know you say "MonthNo is a single cell range name containing 8", just to confirm with you, is the "MonthNo" you stipulate is the named range in the workbook, and not the Connection only Query I have created?
Reason am asking, tried today as above thank you, No Syntax Errors but comes up with an error not able to find the value 8. I have a named range "MonthNo" which only refers to cell E2 and NOT the header cell E1. I also have the Connection Query called "MonthNo".
I will have more time tomorrow as Month-end is out the way, will look at with my colleague with your solution.

Comment: Thank you, appreciated. I tried today late, may have done something wrong, so will try tomorrow with more time. Thank you.
Does there need to be a space between = and "&?
And if "MonthNo" is the named single cell range with 8 in it, is the reference [Content]{0}[Column1] correct? Would I need change the [Column 1] to anyrthing else?

Comment: Thank you horseyride, appreciated, I have got it to work. The MonthNo inserted wasn't returning the 8, however I realised that I had made that range into a Table called MonthNo, and had Defined the Name of the cell.
What I did is reconverted the MonthNo table back to a Range and the Query has worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi horseyride, in the same manner as with the "MonthNo" above you helped me with, how may I reference a list cell "AccountNo" to filter within a query:-
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type2", each ([Account Number] = "&AccountNo&")),
as this doesn't seem to work?
I have added the line at the top
AccountNo= Text.From(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="AccountNo"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]),

Comment: It depends if the AccountNo is a number or text.  Your question assumes text and should work. If its a number, try Number.From in place of Text.From.  Please open new question if you have additional issues

Comment: Wow. and my upvote dissappeared!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't change the query name, the name of below query should be `MonthNo` (same as table name).

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="MonthNo"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Month No", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

The sql string should be updated as below.

- `MonthNo{0}` means the 1st row of table `MonthNo`
- `[Month No]` means column `Month No`
- Using `&` as concate operator to create sql string

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("XXXX\SAGEXXX", "UKXXXXXXLtd", [Query="SELECT ... SYSAccountingPeriod.PeriodNumber = " & MonthNo{0}[Month No] & "...DESC"]),
```

Comment: Thank you taller_ExcelHome, I have just successfully implemented your solution using the table connection and works just as good. Thank you and appreciated for your trouble.